# What is this metal cable in wall?

Tags: drywall, kitchens

I'm adding a window in my kitchen and found this metal cable between two pipes in the corner.  Slab home.

Can someone please let me know what it is?

[image]

Comment: Looks structural - abnormally good hurricane (or tornado) tie all the way to the slab? Florida - oh yeah, that's my bet. Look on top of the wall?

Comment: ...like this? http://www.cabletite.com/Catalog-COMPANY-NEWS_8.aspx

Comment: @Ecnerwal Sure looks like an answer to me.

Comment: My initial thought was a ground path for lightning (btw probably not a good idea in-wall), but I think @Ecnerwal is correct.

Comment: Yep, that's it, @ecnerwal, thanks!!!

Comment: For future reference, @JBinFlorida, providing pics of the ends of the cables would have aided in IDing its purposes. More details are always better than fewer.

Comment: Why is there one bolt in the stud to the left of the cable? Why is the stud installed “flat” in the wall?

Answer (score 2):

So, based on the fact that this cable is dead straight I assumed it to be structural - it's clearly under tension to be that straight. Visually, it appears to be galvanized steel, not something electrical, and electrical is not normally tight.

Tie down made sense. Noting a username implying a Florida location, tie down made a LOT of sense. Keeping your frame attached to the foundation helps immensely in hurricane and tornado survivability.

Brief web search for "structural cable tie slab" found what appears to be [at least one company](http://www.cabletite.com/Catalog-COMPANY-NEWS_8.aspx) making such things. Obviously I'm not associated, and I don't know if there are others.

Comment: Probably not galvanized, just bare steel that is free of rust. Hot dip is done at over 800  F and would soften cold drawn steel wire.

Comment: Wow, OP should move somewhere nice like California where you don't have to tie buildings down to their foundat-- *oh, wait.*

Comment: @blacksmith37 200,000 PSI steel fence wire is galvanized, so high strength is not incompatible with galvanizing, and the surface color looks like zinc to me.

Comment: If it’s that critical to hold the wall down, I wonder why they used OSB board instead of plywood?

Comment: @blacksmith37 fence wires are in not in any way "soft" and are definately galvanised. but this tie down is probably mild steel.